# Wholesale Rol - Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2

I would like to create a new role for my wholesale customers and that these customers can see the prices without taxes, and that they can see the total taxes at the end (checkout). But I can not find a way to do it. Any ideas to help me get this?